# RDP into my server works except on a specific network

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

I have a weird issue where I can RDP into my server using my laptop at home, but when I try doing the same thing at work(**same computer**, different network), I can't remote into it anymore.

I know that the server is up and running because I can RDP into another computer, and from there successfully connect to the problematic server.

I am using a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 (Windows 8.1) with the latest updates.

Any suggestions on what I can do to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Comment: What's the relationship between your work network and your server's network? Are they on same network? If not, do you have some form of VPN service going on? If not, there is no way you can RDP into a server from a network not allowed to do so...

Comment: No relationship between the work network and the server's network. My server network, work network, and the 3rd (working) network are all different. I didn't specify allow the 3rd network in question to connect nor did I specify the work network to NOT connect...

Comment: Perhaps the work network doesn't allow outgoing RDP connections?

Comment: From the work network, I am able to connect to a 3rd computer (on a separate network) through RDP, so the work network will at least allow some outgoing RDP connections.

Comment: Try pinging your home network from the work network.  Assuming your router will reply to the ping.  This at least lets you know that you can get to your router on the work network.  If you can get a successful ping, then it has to be a firewall issue.

Comment: Does the server you're trying to remote into have any firewall settings that might be blocking traffic from your work network specifically?  Also see if your home and work networks are the same network type (public, guest or private) in Network and Sharing Center.  If not, your laptop itself could have different firewall settings for each location you're working from -- i.e., the work profile could be more restrictive than home.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you carefully make sure you have a checkmark on each of these pre-requisites for RDP on different networks as found on [Microsoft webpage](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network)

> ```
> There are six steps you'll need to follow to set this up. Each one is explained in detail below.
>
> Allow remote connections to the computer you want to access.
>
> Make sure Remote Desktop is able to communicate through your firewall.
>
> Find the IP address of the computer on your home network that you want to connect to.
>
> Open your router's configuration screen and forward TCP port 3389 to the destination computer's IP address.
>
> Find your router's public IP address so that Remote Desktop can find it on the Internet.
>
> Open Remote Desktop Connection and connect.
> ```

Comment: BTW, @confusedKid - you will need 2 RDP 'bookmarks' to do this, one from each location, as the connection data will be totally different for each.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the configuration of the server, as I can access it using the laptop on a 3rd network with no issues. I only seem to have problems when trying to connect with the laptop on a specific network (the work network).